# dhtmlx Gantt: How to update parents automatically of a custom date column

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

My Gannt is constructed in the following way:

[image: Gantt table]

In the first column  with a date on the image above, if I change the value of a lightbox, it updates the parents to the value earliest date by itself.

How could I configure the highlighted column to have the same behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `start_date` or `end_date` parameter of a child task, the changes may affect its parent task with the `project` task type. But Gantt doesn't check other parameters. 
You need to implement a custom solution by using Gantt API and Javascript.
The easiest way for that would be to use the `eachParent` method in the `onAfterTaskUpdate` event:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_eachparent.html

Here is an example of how it might be implemented:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/66c4901d1